# Using integer as dictionary key using dict()

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to use numbers as my dict key. Is there anyway to initiate the dictionary using dict() method?

This works

```
mydict = { '100':'hundred', '200':'two hundred'}
```

This doesn't work?

```
mydict = dict( 100='hundred' )
```

The error says 'keyword can't be an expression' and I couldn't find any solution.

Thank you.

Comment: `mydict = dict({100: 'hundred'})`? Not sure if there's a more straight forward way except just `mydict = {100: 'hundred'}`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it mist be a valid python identifier, so it cannot start with a number.

You can read where i found it at here in the part about dict

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Like the comment above says you can use an int, since dictionaries just hash the string and you get an int anyways, in the case of an int it just hashes to itself. But it doesnt work with dict ()

On that page it shows you can do

mydict = dict (zip ([1], ["one"]))

Which is kinda ugly imo, but seems to get the job done

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your question exactly,  but you mentioned to use number as dict key right? you just directly initiate it using integer instead string like this..

```
a = {1:'one',100:'hundered'}
print a
{1: 'one', 100: 'hundrered'}
```

Comment: Hi there, I was trying to do that exact same thing as your example, only with dict( ) instead of { }

Comment: for that you may use like this, create your input as a tuples, like (1,'one') , (2,'two') pass those as a list of dict... like dict([((1,'one') , (2,'two'))] . ......    i.e:- >>> a = (1,'one')  >>>  b = (2,'two')  >>> dict([a,b]) you will get like this, {1: 'one', 2: 'two'}

Answer (score 0):

To use the `dict` method you need to feed it a list or tuple of lists or tuples.

```
>>> dict([(100, 'hundred'), (200, 'two hundred')])
{200: 'two hundred', 100: 'hundred'}
```